# Does collectd support arbitary nesting of metrics?

Tags: metrics, graphite, collectd

As per the [collectd naming schema](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Naming_schema) - metrics dumped out of collectd plugins need to follow this structure

```
host / plugin - plugin_instance / type - type_instance
```

That works fine for system metrics like cpu, memory, etc. but for an application that exposes its health status via a health URL can have arbitary nested of parameters of the form

```
{"datacenter": {"region": {"server": {"service": {"parameter": value } } } } }
```

which when dispatched by collectd should be translated into a graphite schema of

```
$datacenter.$region.$server.$service.$parameter = $value
```

But the current collectd naming schema does not allow that. How can one achieve that in collectd?

Answer (score 2):

Others have faced this issue as mentioned [here](https://github.com/collectd/collectd/issues/419)

I found a roundabout way of doing this:

1. Instead of [collectd-python plugin](https://collectd.org/documentation/manpages/collectd-python.5.shtml), use the [collectd exec plugin](https://collectd.org/documentation/manpages/collectd-exec.5.shtml)
2. Change the [write_graphite](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Write_Graphite) plugin to have **EscapeCharacter** as "."
3. Restart collectd.

Now if I write an exec plugin:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTNAME="${COLLECTD_HOSTNAME:-localhost}"
INTERVAL="${COLLECTD_INTERVAL:-10}"

function gen_random() {
  echo $RANDOM  % 10 + 1 | bc
}

while sleep "$INTERVAL"; do
  VALUE=$(do_magic)
  echo "PUTVAL \"$HOSTNAME/region.datacenter.rack.cluster.server.service/gauge-service_parameter\" interval=$INTERVAL N:$VALUE" | tee -a /var/tmp/test.log; 
done
```

That will create the following hierarchy in graphite:

```
region/
region/datacenter
region/datacenter/rack
region/datacenter/rack/cluster
region/datacenter/rack/cluster/server
region/datacenter/rack/cluster/server/service
region/datacenter/rack/cluster/server/service/gauge-service_parameter.wsp
```

Notice that the prefix "gauge" is important because collectd needs to know the type of value being pushed.